# C - Can't read user integer input

Tags: c, user-input, fgets, strtol

I'm trying to read user integer input with the following code.  I'm aware that strtol returns a long value.

```
long color = 1;
char buf[256];
char * last;

while(color != 0){
    printf("Enter a color (0 to stop): ");
    fgets(buf, 256, stdin);

    color = strtol(buf, &last, 10);

    if(last != '\0'){
        printf("You didn't enter a number.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("%d\n", color);
    }
}
```

I tried running this, first entering 4, which gave me `You didn't enter a number.`  I tried it again with "forty" and got the same result.  What am I missing here?  All I want to do is get basic user input for an integer value that verifies only an integer was entered.  I don't need a long because the values will all be between 3000 and 4000.

Comment: `last` is a pointer, but you compare it to `\0` which is `int`. Don't you get any warnings?

Comment: No, the only warnings I get are for unused variables which are part of something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last != '\0'` is equivalent to `last != NULL`. You're testing whether `last` is a null pointer, which it never is, because `strtol` never sets `*endptr` to `NULL`.

You should probably do this instead:

```
if (last == buf || *last != '\0')
```

(The first condition handles the case where `buf` is an empty string.)

There's a secondary problem in your input code:

```
fgets(buf, 256, stdin);
```

This line does not check the return value of `fgets` to make sure `buf` was filled, and it does not remove the trailing newline of any user input.

Do this instead:

```
if (!fgets(buf, 256, stdin)) {
    break;
}
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

As for why `'\0'` acts as a null pointer here:

Any integer constant expression with value zero is implicitly converted to a null pointer if used in a pointer context. `'\0'` is such a zero-valued integer expression, and you're comparing it to a pointer, so it is in pointer context.

Comment: Tried this and I'm still getting the `You didn't enter a number.` message, even though I tested this with 5.

Comment: @user3308219 That's because `buf` is `"5\n"` in your program, not `"5"`.

Comment: @user3308219 Oh, I had `!=` where I meant to use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Change that `if(last != '\0')` to `if( *last != '\0')`.  You want to check what `last` ***points to***

From https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first
> invalid character in *endptr. If there were no digits at all, strtol()
> stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0).
>
> In
> particular, if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return, the
> entire string is valid.

Answer (score 0):

For OP's specific case, it is sufficient to test for extra non-numeric text after the number.

```
char buf[256];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) Handle_EndOfFile();
char *last;
long color = strtol(buf, &last, 10);

while (isspace(*last)) last++; // tolerate trailing white-space like '\n'

// Do not compare the pointer, compare what it points to
// if(last != '\0'){
if (*last || color < 3000 || color > 4000) {
  Handle_NonNumeric("You didn't enter a number in 3000-4000 range.\n");
} else {
  foo(color); // Success
}
```